# How to set fire render colors to be the same as the fire viewport preview?

Tags: rendering, shaders, smoke-simulation

I am modeling a candle in Blender, and I want the flame to have the same shading look as it does in rendered view. This is in the viewport (wireframe):

[image]

This is rendered:

[image]

See how there is a slight purplish color in the center of the frame? How can I set the preview color to look the same as in rendered view?

Comment: Hi. Please try to use existing tags when asking a question. New tags can be suggested on the meta site: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Flames look better on a dark background.  But it seems that in your color ramp the first color has no alpha channel, so hard edges are visible.

[image: missing alpha channel?]

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I wasn't done changing all of the settings for the flame. What I am asking is if I can set the *viewport* color of the fire to somehow have some similarity to the color of the actual rendered flame so that I can see what I am working with without my computer lagging trying to adjust the colors in rendered view. This would be extremely helpful, as I waste plenty of time waiting for rendering pictures to become visible.

Comment: At the moment the viewport is black, but the final image has a bright color. This affects the color of the flame.
Try the following: First change the  background color of the viewport so that it looks similar to the final image, then you can adjust the colors of the flame.